# Admob banner setAdUnitId

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, smartbanner

I need to set  the admob banner ad unit id programatically in java class

```
  mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
  mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
```

and at the same time use xml for layout

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I tried this but it didn't work as it shows an error:
       `Required XML attribute “adSize” was missing`

Please help

Comment: just follow this tutorial https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=vi

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Put it on **onCreate** :

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                        .build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Put in **Xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/BANNER_ID" />
```

Put in **String file**:

```
<string name="BANNER_ID">Your Banner Id</string>
```

Comment: But I said I need to set the id "setAdUnitId" programatically not in xml